# Using matplotlib.pyplot from a Gtk app

Tags: python, matplotlib, gtk

I implemented a very simple Gtk app on python 2.7 that all it does is opens a main window. What I would like to do is to open yet another window and plot some data using pyplot upon user's input. For now to make things simpler, I just ignore processing user input, and I just try to plot something from the **init** function of my main application window.

Unfortunately, this does not work as expected. The main App window opens up as expected, but the window from the plt.plot() command seems to be completely dead. Nothing is plotted and I can not even close the window, unless I first close the main-app window.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a sample of the code I am trying to run.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class MyGraphApp():    
    def __init__(self):
        self.geometry = (500, 500)
        self.main_win = self.create_window_layout()             # main window        
        self.fig = plt.figure()
        plt.plot([0,10], [10, 10])

    def destroy(self, widget, data=None):
        Gtk.main_quit()

    def main(self):
        Gtk.main()

    def create_window_layout(self):
        win = Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
        self.main_vbox = Gtk.VBox(False, 1)
        self.main_vbox.set_border_width(1)
        win.add(self.main_vbox)
        self.main_vbox.show()

        self.headerbar = Gtk.HeaderBar(title="Main Window")
        self.headerbar.props.show_close_button = True                
        win.set_titlebar(self.headerbar)

        win.set_default_size(self.geometry[0], self.geometry[1])
        win.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        win.connect("delete_event", self.destroy) 
        win.show_all() 

        return win

myGraphApp = MyGraphApp()
myGraphApp.main()
```

Comment: Hi! What did you try? Did you find the piece of code which causes the hangup?

Comment: It's not that things "hang up". What happens is that the window that contains the figure does not respond to any user interface: all buttons are not responding, you can not close the window, and you can not even see the plot itself.

Comment: You could comment out all lines in your code, and then let it run and add a line of code back on every subsequent try. Thus, you learn whether there is a certain line of code causing the trouble or the thing as a whole is screwed up...

Comment: The problem is not the code. the problem is interaction of Gtk with the matplotlib backend. And since I don't know much about backends I thought to ask the community

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. However, starting it in a separate Thread might help. It might also be worth thinking about embedding the widgets [directly](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_gtk3.py) into your window.

Comment: elya5 thanks for the suggestion. I tried your code and it definitely solves my problem.

Comment: elya5 thanks for the suggestion. I tried your code and it definitely solves my problem. I do have a quick follow up question: It seems that you did try the code sample I provided above. So when you try the code you should see two windows, one that is the main Gtk window app and another one opened by the plt.figure() command. Do you see anything on the second window and does it response to user commands (for example zooming in/out)? In my case it's completely unresponsive. It begins to respond to user input, only after the main GTK window is closed.